# Por que la fecha de modificación es diferente a la real ?? - ANDROID

Tags: php, android

tengo un problema no grande, pero engorroso...
Tengo un dispositivo android que corre PHP y genera diferentes archivos. 
Por alguna razón, estos archivos tienen una hora totalmente diferente a la des dispositivo.

Por ejemplo:

Un archivo PHP crea un log.txt siendo la fecha 12-05-2021 y la hora real 15:00
Por alguna razón, la "Fecha de Modificación" que aparece en el sistema dice: "12-05-2021 19:00:00"

Hasta ahora he revisado la fecha del sistema...
La fecha y zona horaria del PHP... 
Fecha y hora de programas en el dispositivo...
Y no obtengo cambios.

```
$xmlTxt = "logXML.txt";
$logXml = fopen($xmlTxt, "a+");
$date = new DateTime();
$timeZone = $date->getTimezone();
fwrite($logXml, $timeZone->getName() . PHP_EOL);
fclose($logXml);
```

Comment: El código de PHP de cómo obtienes la fecha.

Comment: listo amigo @Bicho

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. En el servidor la fecha/hora será siempre la misma (según la zona horaria que tenga el servidor por defecto). En Android las fechas/horas serán según la zona horaria de cada dispositivo. Si alguien tiene tu app instalada en China tendrá la zona horaria de China, y así por cada país o bien otra zona horaria que haya definido en los ajustes. Tu app puede estar instalada en miles de dispositivos cada uno con su zona horaria. Teniendo eso claro, explícanos ahora cuál es el problema.

Comment: Y si fue instalada en china, como rayos le cambio la hora o la zona horaria al sistema ??

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `date_default_timezone_set()` en el archivo php y seleccionas tu zona horaria. El código sería así:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');

    $date = new DateTime('now');
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";//Imprime 2021-05-12 15:09:17
?>
```

Este es el link con las [Zonas horarias](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) soportadas en PHP.

Comment: Eso está hecho, la zona horaria se aplica si obtengo la fecha en el PHP... lo que yo dije, es que la fecha de modificación del sistema android no tiene la zona horaria aplicada...